# Javascript: get the number of json objects when using @Html.Raw

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

To get a list of c# objects I'm using the following Javascript code:

```
    var objectList= '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.ObjectList))';
```

How would I get the number of objects within objectList?

I tried using .length and .size().

Comment: when in doubt take a look at the page source...what's there? Can also log the data to console to inspect it

Comment: What does the json consist of?

Comment: Can you `console.log` your `objectList`?

Answer (score 0):

What you are setting is a `string` type to `objectList`, try:

```
var objectList = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.ObjectList));
console.log(objectList.length);
```

Inspect the DOM in F12 tools to make sure the JSON is correct.